# How does ConcurrentQueue work?

Tags: c#, queue

How does it work?

I know that, you put a type in, and then you can receive it on another thread, and also get a `bool` at the same time.

But what i don´t get it, how does it send the item?

for example, in Thread 1, i have a *byte array* in which i write some data, then put it into a Queue.

Then Thread 2, will use `TryDequeue(out byte[])` to receive it.
How does this work?

As TryDequeue, will have to write it to another `byte[]`, so i am guessing, it´s doing some kind of copy?

Meaning, if the `byte[]` that Thread 1 is writing to is `public`, Thread 2 can read to it faster/better as it doesn´t have to be copied?

Though the problem is that it doesn´t know when it´s allowed to read.

EDIT:

Here is an example when i use it:

```
while (True)
{
    var tempBytes = new byte[length];
    tempBytes.Write(....);
    Queue.Enqueue(tempBytes);
    read = true;
}



While(true)
{

    if (Queue.TryDequeue(out TextureData))
    {
         ................
    }              
});
```

So, when Thread 1, makes a new tempBytes, will the reference given to Thread 2 be, invalid?
Or does a new byte array, become a new reference, meaning it doesn´t matter for Thread 2?

EDIT 2:

Fixed the sample codes to fit people wishes:)

Comment: It is a queue data structure.  You can google that phrase and read all about them.  I don't know if it's spec'd out what algorithms the C# implementation uses to make enqueue/dequeue safe across threads, but you could write an entire book on different techniques, from a single lock (simplest), to multiple locks for head and tail, to lock-free algorithms which are based on atomic primitives such as compare-and-swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As TryDequeue, will have to write it to another byte[], so i am guessing, it´s doing some kind of copy?

No it doesn't. All arrays in .NET are reference types. So the Queue only stores and returns a reference.

That also implies that the thread that Enqueues the data should then forget about it. The contents of the array are not made 'thread-safe' by the ConcurrentQuue.

> Meaning, if the byte[] that Thread 1 is writing to is public, Thread 2 can read to it faster/better as it doesn't have to be copied?

`public` or `private` does not matter here. As long as the sending code can access the array it will work.

Comment: So, does that mean, if Byte[] U that Thread 1 Queues will become a pointer to U from Thread 2?  And when Thread 1 then overwrites U, it´s written at another place, and then that pointer get´s queued? Meaning, Thread 2 only get "shortcuts"? And when i said "Public" i just mean, that i make a byte[] available in the entire class, so any thread can write read, any time they want.

Comment: Thread1 will also only have a reference (pointer) to the array. The references are copied, the data is not. And many threads can read an array but writing should usually be synchronized.

Comment: @user2587718 `So, does that mean, if Byte[] U that Thread 1 Queues will become a pointer to U from Thread 2? And when Thread 1 then overwrites U, it´s written at another place, and then that pointer get´s queued?` No They share the same array.

Comment: Wait, so, if i Enqueue a byte[] and right after i dispose of it (null it), and will Thread 2 then get a null byte[]? As it get´s the reference to that byte[] which after being queued was nulled (When i say nulled, i simply mean, it´s no data in it).

Comment: You can only null the reference, not the data. So Thread2 will get the old (valid) reference to the array.

Comment: `if i Enqueue a byte[]`, Now there are two references to your array. Now read previous comment.

Comment: Oh, well, look at my example in my edited Answer, just to be sure:)

Comment: @user2587718 Henk may want to read it, But I am sure I won't. I am not interested in reading unrelated codes for the problem.

Comment: It´s not unrelated, it´s an example of use with the Queueing, and just want to know if it will work, as i think it will. No need to understand or read the code itself, i just copy pasted so you can see the while loop etc.

Comment: @user2587718 You don't get me. what is the relation of this codes with your problem. **`sprite.Begin(SharpDX.Direct3D9.SpriteFlags.None);
    device.BeginScene();`**

Comment: `i just copy pasted so you can see the while loop`. No don't do it. My time is as valuable as yours. Provide a summary code.

Comment: @user2587718 - Your code looks basically OK. Each run of the outer while creates a `byte[]` and then hands it of.  You may have efficiency problems when this is XNA though. I don't know SharpDX. (Conversation closed. You should focus your questions better, the 2 edits look indeed unrelated).

Comment: @LV4, i just copy pasted, as always when i don´t show the entire code, people say, (Show the whole code), so now i did it. And well, even then it´s wrong;S.

Comment: @Henk, Great, that´s what i want to do, just hand the byte[], then a new, forever, thanks:)  I am interested to know the efficiency problems ( i know it´s far from optimal, as i am lacking in skills at this), but i would gladly hear it, so i can hopefully make some improvements:)

Comment: @user2587718 its not about right or wrong, you're asking a question and showing 300 lines or unrelated code and saying, will this work? Where what we want you to do is post the portion of code that does what you are describing instead of your 300 lines of code which in most cases will nail it down to 1 or a few lines no more than 10.

Comment: @Prix, think you missunderstood. I didn´t want to know if the entire code would work or not. What i wanted to know was, if i use the Queue in that way ( meaning 2 while loops in 2 threads) will it be able to read and write without problem, or will they read and write to each other. And the answer was that it will work as they send references, then make a new reference.

Comment: But, changed the codes now, hopefully they are correct now. and will help people to understand what i was meaning with it.